# How to do responsive path

Tags: javascript, css, svg, path

anyone know how to do responsive svg path as the link below?

https://visitmaine.com/quarterly/chasingthesun/explore/arrival/go

I really can't find the ways.

I did my testing site https://ideal-works.com/ngeeannopenhouse/

```js
function positionCar()
{
  var  scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
  var  maxScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  var  path = document.getElementById("path1");
  // Calculate distance along the path the car should be for the current scroll amount
  var  pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
  var  dist = pathLen * scrollY / maxScrollY;
  var  pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
 
  // Position the car at "pos" totated by "angle"
  var  car = document.getElementById("car");
  car.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + pos.x + "," + pos.y + ")");
}


// Reposition car whenever there is a scroll event
window.addEventListener("scroll", positionCar);

// Position the car initially
positionCar();
```

```html
<svg id="svgPath" width="100%" height="100%" x="0px" y="0px" style="overflow: visible;">

 
 <path d="M585.1,30v1242.2c0,0-25.8,233.9,66.5,367.8s175.5,257.8-55.2,434.3c0,0-86.9,57.9-179.1,66.9
 c-92.3,9-89.6,52.5-88.7,90.5c0.9,38,48.9,115.8,141.1,143.9s115.8,59.7,115.8,104.9c0,45.2,0,1191.5,0,1191.5s1.8,22.6-19.9,56.1
 c-21.7,33.5-59.7,85-86.9,143.9c0,0-52.5,93.2,148.4,310.3c0,0,153.8,146.6,212.6,240.7s-117.6,165.6-186.4,203.6
 c-68.8,38-294,143.9-274.1,306.7c19.9,162.9,154.7,251.5,218.9,337.5s131.2,163.8,125.8,301.3c-5.4,137.5-91.4,215.3-110.4,252.4
 c-19,37.1-28,53.4-28,70.6s0,1836.6,0,1836.6s-10,54.3,42.5,129.4c52.5,75.1,49.8,105.9,15.4,185.5s-111.3,191.8-57.9,318.5
 s63.3,194.5,19,291.3c0,0-18.1,31.7-19,58.8c-0.9,27.1,0,1690.9,0,1690.9s-11.8,60.6,45.2,124.9c57,64.2,148.4,137.5,147.5,198.1
 s-109.5,98.6-171,140.2c-61.5,41.6-154.7,98.6-150.2,181.9c4.5,83.2,152,167.4,189.1,182.8c37.1,15.4,203.6,70.6,245.2,209
 c41.6,138.4-180.9,336.6-300.4,439.7c-119.4,103.1-228,191.8-200.8,274.1c27.1,82.3,103.1,195.4,145.7,247.9
 c42.5,52.5,201.8,219.8,192.7,323c-9,103.1-73.3,172.8-105.9,208.1c-32.6,35.3-33.5,59.7-34.4,85s-2.7,540.9-2.7,1780.9"
    id="path1" 
               style="opacity: 0.25; fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; stroke-dashoffset: 1e-05; stroke-dasharray: none;"></path>
   
 
 <image id="car" xlink:href="https://ideal-works.com/ngeeannopenhouse/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Gradient-marker-02.png" height="34" width="34"></image>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please note that Stackoverflow is not a coding service, and we expect you to have done your research and come up with an attempt at solving your own task.

Comment: add a viewBox attribute if you want things to be responsive.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for reply, from the link - https://visitmaine.com/quarterly/chasingthesun/explore/arrival/go,

Comment: everytime when we first load or reload the page, the svg path will auto calculate the starting point to ending point and the "circle svg in the link always in the middle when scrolling down